# a map with MapKit in Swift gives error "unable to type-check this expression"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Xcode gives the following error:

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

```swift
import MapKit
import SwiftUI

struct Home: View {
    @State private var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = .region(.myRegion)
    @State private var mapSelection: MKMapItem?
    @Namespace private var locationSpace
    @State private var viewingRegion: MKCoordinateRegion?
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    @State private var showSearch: Bool = false
    @State private var searchResults: [MKMapItem] = []
    @State private var showDetails: Bool = false
    @State private var lookAroundScene: MKLookAroundScene?
    @State private var routeDisplaying: Bool = false
    @State private var route: MKRoute?
    @State private var routeDestination: MKMapItem?
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Map(position: $cameraPosition, selection: $mapSelection, scope: locationSpace) {
                // Marker("Apple Park", systemImage: "applelogo", coordinate: .myLocation)
                //     .tint(.black)
                Annotation("Apple Park", coordinate: .myLocation) {
                    ZStack {
                        Image(systemName: "applelogo")
                            .font(.title3)
                        
                        Image(systemName: "square")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                    }
                }
                .annotationTitles(.hidden)
                
                ForEach(searchResults, id: \.self) { mapItem in
                    if routeDisplaying {
                        mapItem == routeDestination {
                            let placemark = mapItem.placemark
                            Marker(placemark.name ?? "Place", coordinate: placemark.coordinate)
                                .tint(.blue)
                        }
                    } else {
                        let placemark = mapItem.placemark
                        Marker(placemark.name ?? "Place", coordinate: placemark.coordinate)
                            .tint(.blue)
                    }
                }
                
                // display route using polyline
                if let route {
                    MapPolyline(route.polyline)
                        // applying bigger stroke
                        .stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 7)
                }
                
                UserAnnotation()
            }
            
            .onMapCameraChange { ctx in
                viewingRegion = ctx.region
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                VStack(spacing: 15) {
                    MapCompass(scope: locationSpace)
                    MapPitchToggle(scope: locationSpace)
                    MapUserLocationButton(scope: locationSpace)
                }
                .buttonBorderShape(.circle)
                .padding()
            }
            .mapScope(locationSpace)
            .navigationTitle("Map")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            
            .searchable(text: $searchText, isPresented: $showSearch)
            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbarBackground(.ultraThinMaterial, for: .navigationBar)
            
            // when route is displayed hide top and bottom bar
            toolbar(routeDisplaying ? .hidden : .visible, for: .navigationBar)
                .sheet(isPresented: $showDetails, onDismiss: {
                    withAnimation(.snappy) {
                        if let boundingRect = route?.polyline.boundingMapRect {
                            cameraPosition = .rect(boundingRect)
                        }
                    }
                }, content: { mapDetails()
                    .presentationDetents([.height(300)])
                    .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled(upThrough: .height(300)))
                    .presentationCornerRadius(25)
                    .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
                })
                .safeAreaInsert(edge: .bottom) {
                    if routeDisplaying {
                        Button("End Route") {
                            withAnimation(.snappy) {
                                routeDisplaying = false
                                showDetails = true
                                mapSelection = routeDestination
                                routeDestination = nil
                                route = nil
                                cameraPosition = .region(.myRegion)
                            }
                        }
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .padding(.vertical, 12)
                        .background(.red.gradient, in: .rect(cornerRadies: 15))
                        .padding()
                        .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                    }
                }
        }
        .onSubmit(of: .search) {
            Task {
                guard !searchText.isEmpty else { return }
                await searchPlaces()
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: showSearch, initial: false) {
            if !showSearch {
                searchResults.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                showDetails = false
                withAnimation(.snappy) {
                    cameraPosition = .region(.myRegion)
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: mapSelection) { _, newValue in
            showDetails = newValue != nil
            // fetching look around preview whenever selection changes
            fetchLookAroundPreview()
        }
    }
    
    // map details view
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func mapDetails() -> some View {
        VStack(spacing: 15) {
            ZStack {
                if lookAroundScene == nil {
                    ContentUnavailableView("No preview available", image: "eye.slash")
                } else {
                    LookAroundPreview(scene: $lookAroundScene)
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 200)
            .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 15))
            
            // close button
            .overlay(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                Button(action: {
                    // closing view
                    showDetails = false
                    withAnimation(.snappy) {
                        mapSelection = nil
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .background(.white, in: .circle)
                })
                .padding(10)
            }
            
            // Direction button
            Button("Get Directions", action: fetchRoute)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding(.vertical, 12)
                .background(.blue.gradient, in: .rect(cornerRadius: 15))
        }
        .padding(15)
    }
    
    func searchPlaces() async {
        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchText
        request.region = viewingRegion ?? .myRegion

        let results = try? await MKLocalSearch(request: request).start()
        searchResults = results?.mapItems ?? []
    }
    
    func fetchLookAroundPreview() {
        if let mapSelection {
            // clearing old one
            lookAroundScene = nil
            Task {
                let request = MKLookAroundSceneRequest(mapItem: mapSelection)
                lookAroundScene = try? await request.scene
            }
        }
    }
    
    // fetching route
    func fetchRoute() {
        if let mapSelection {
            let request = MKDirections.Request()
            request.source = .init(placemark: .init(coordinate: .myLocation))
            request.destination = mapSelection
           
            Task {
                let result = try? await MKDirections(request: request).calculate()
                route = result?.routes.first
                routeDestination = mapSelection
                
                withAnimation(.snappy) {
                    routeDisplaying = true
                    showDetails = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    static var myLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return .init(latitude: 37.3346, longitude: -122.0090)
    }
}

extension MKCoordinateRegion {
    static var myRegion: MKCoordinateRegion {
        return .init(center: .myLocation, latitudinalMeters: 10000, longitudinalMeters: 10000)
    }
}
```

Here is the error screenshot:

[image]

I am using Xcode 15.0.1 with iOS 17.

Comment: Repeating the recommendation that oftentimes works here, comment out different parts of the code until you have identified the issue.

Comment: It is a typo somewhere

Comment: The leading dot of `.toolbar` is missing. Generally it's a good practice to check the leading dots of all modifiers.